# Stuck in while loop?

Tags: c++

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong. It's not outputting anything when I execute so I'm assuming its stuck somewhere and goes on endlessly. Assignment is as follows -- "Write a program that reads a file consisting of students' test scores in the range 0-200. It should then determine the number of students having scores   in each of the following ranges: 0-24,25-49,50-74,75-99,100-124,125-149,150-174,175-200. Output the input data."

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream outFile;
    ifstream inFile;
    int num;
    int category[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };



    outFile.open("testscores.txt");
    if (!outFile)
    {
        cout << "outFile open failed." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    outFile << "blah blah" << endl << endl;
    inFile.open("scorestest.txt");
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "infile failed" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    inFile >> num;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        if (num < 25)
            category[0]++;
        else if (num < 50)
            category[1]++;
        else if (num < 75)
            category[2]++;
        else if (num < 100)
            category[3]++;
        else if (num < 125)
            category[4]++;
        else if (num < 150)
            category[5]++;
        else if (num < 175)
            category[6]++;
        else if (num < 200)
            category[7]++;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        cout << "Number of Grades between" << category[i] << endl;
        outFile << "Number of Grades between" << category[i] << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Been struggling on this for a bit. Is it perhaps my inFile? I've rewrote different code three times to get this program to work with no luck

Comment: You're not reading from your inFile in the while loop, so you're never reaching the end of file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Step through it with your debugger, *see* what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not advancing in the file, you are operating on the one `num` you read before the while without reading any more `nums` so youre not getting to the end of the file at all.